# Sn1 mechanism and concentration of neucleophile

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

Why is low concentration of neucleophile  preferred in Sn1 mechanism?

Comment: You already asked this [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/43782/23444).